# SerialPort (.net) - not ports found

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

public static void getPorts()
{
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

    Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");

    foreach (string port in ports)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(port);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have problem with this simple code. I need to write out my ports because I will work with them later on (I'm using that simple function in my bigger app). Everything was working until I upgraded my Windows. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? I have also installed all drivers.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Are you getting any errors? Please add `try-catch` block in code.

Comment: am I right when I assume that you ports have disappeared?

Comment: Can you see the ports in Device Manager

Comment: I don't get any error but also any port names. Usually output was COM3, COM4 etc. Code runs but SerialPort.GetPortNames(); do not find any port so it don't write out any.  Output is just "The following serial ports were found:" from WriteLine()

Comment: I don't even have Ports option like I used to (like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv1pw.png), i have them listed there but not with COM names http://imgur.com/a/t405K

Answer (score 1):

The `SerialPort.GetPortNames` method won't list some virtual serial ports (like those provided by some USB-to-RS232 adapters etc.), since it relies on the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` registry key as specified in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).
You can sse a WMI query to list all serial ports, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23651956/248534).